# contar las veces que sale un "x" nombre en un xml

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy teniendo este problema, lo que quiero es leer el xml y en el tag *nombre* me diga cuantas veces aparece el nombre de "cesar" por ejemplo, intente hacerlo con linq sin exito, el codigo con el que lo intente es este:

```
XElement xEmp = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\Curso\Desktop\xmls\ventas.xml");
            var empNames = from nombre in xEmp.Elements("cesar")
                           select nombre;
```

Así se ve el xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfClass_ventas xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <class_ventas>
    <nombre>empleado</nombre>
    <mesa>2</mesa>
    <producto>gatorade</producto>
  </class_ventas>
  <class_ventas>
    <nombre>cesar</nombre>
    <mesa>3</mesa>
    <producto>agua</producto>
  </class_ventas>
</ArrayOfClass_ventas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar la funcion count de linq, tu error esta en que no estas referenciando un nodo xml en la funcion Elements de xEmp

```
XElement xEmp = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\Curso\Desktop\xmls\ventas.xml");
            var empNames = (from c in xEmp.Elements("class_ventas")
                         where (string)c.Element("nombre") == "cesar"
                         select c).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(empNames.Count());
```

Comment: Si tiene bien escrito el linq? por que me sale que tengo 0 coincidencias pero si tengo

Comment: Edite la pregunta para que veas la estructura del xml

Comment: edite la respuesta para que use tu estructura de xml